# How does GTK register URI handlers?

Tags: gtk

I use Google Chrome on my Debian laptop, but at one point I had Firefox installed. Now I'm developing a GTK application, and when I click on a link, it outputs this:

```
(charry.phpw:6267): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to show 'http://t.co/nOOjE9u1': Failed to execute child process "/opt/firefox/firefox" (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand why it would be calling for Firefox, because I have x-www-browser set to Chrome. Does anyone have insight as to how GTK picks a browser to open hyperlinks?

Now I have to expand this question. I woke up this morning and tried to run this application on my Windows box, but it says:

```
<php.exe:3360>: Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to show 'http://t.co/tKtwKbAt': No application is registered as handling this file
```

So how does GTK register URI handlers? No one on the Internet seems to know how to do this...without Gnome, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK uses GVFS, which *used to use* scheme settings from Gconf (`/desktop/gnome/uri-handlers`), but has since switched to XDG MIME Actions spec, with preferences kept in `${XDG_DATA_HOME-~/.local/share}/applications`.

`~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
```

The `.desktop` files are looked for in the subfolder `applications` of both `$XDG_DATA_HOME` and every path listed in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

If `mimeapps.list` does not exist, `defaults.list` will be used.

---

I don't know the answer for Windows (yet), but [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) will be useful in determining the location.